# Constructor selection precedence in a C++ class

Tags: c++

Please help with this sample code:

```
struct A
{
   std::string value;
  
   A() {}
   A(A const &) {}
  
   template <typename... Args>
   A(Args&&... args) : value (std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}
};
  
int main(void)
{
   auto a = A();
   auto b = a;
  
   return 0;
}
```

An error is thrown while compiling:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::basic_string(A&)’
```

For some reason the compiler wants to call the templated constructor even though the class has a copy constructor.
So the question is - why the compiler does not see copy constructor?

Comment: I imagine it'll be because it looks for a function taking a non-const reference first and finds your template

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your example, the template constructor is a better match than the non-template constructor because of the universal reference the template constructor uses, which allows the compiler to pass the lvalue `a` to the constructor *as-is*, whilst the non-template one requires it to be a `const` lvalue.

If instead of declaring a like this:

```
auto a = A();
```

You declared it like this

```
const auto a = A();
```

Then the copy constructor would be chosen instead, since it would be a better match.

To make your example work, you will need to use [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) or concepts (if using at least C++20).

With SFINAE:

```
struct A
{
   std::string value;
  
   A() {}
   A(A const &) {}
  
   template <typename Arg, typename... Args,
        std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<A, std::remove_reference_t<Arg>>>* = nullptr>
    A(Arg &&arg, Args&&... args): value (std::forward<Arg>(arg), std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}
};
```

With concepts:

```
struct A
{
   std::string value;
  
   A() {}
   A(A const &) {}
  
    template <typename Arg, typename... Args>
    requires (!std::same_as<A, std::remove_reference_t<Arg>>)
    A(Arg &&arg, Args&&... args): value (std::forward<Arg>(arg), std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}
};
```

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing special about constructors. It uses the same rules as normal function lookup. See [overloading over.match](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.best#general). When there is an f(const T&) and a f(T&&) the function without constant/reference arguments is selected first.